Google API in DotNet Core, set up ClassroomService
I can't figure out how to set up dot net ClassroomService based on the sample Python code:
classroom_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    serviceName="classroom"
    version="v1",
    discoveryServiceUrl=f"https://classroom.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?labels=ADD_ONS_ALPHA&key={GOOGLE_API_KEY}",
    credentials=credentials)

In dot net, I use the following successfully for Google Classroom calls, but it doesn't work with the new Classroom Add On feature.
using (var classroomService = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken),
    ApplicationName = "App Test",
    
    
}))
{...

I think it's the discoveryServiceUrl that is set up wrong in dot net, since it needs the labels param.  How can I make sure this is set up correctly in dot net?
There's no DiscoveryServiceUrl field that I see anywhere.

I think the example you're looking at is slightly out of date; the Classroom add-on API endpoints are now generally available. You don't need to specify any special Discovery Service URL.
For .NET, I would recommend using the Classroom API Client Library for .NET. You can download the library package from NuGet.
I've submitted a change to remove outstanding references to the ADD_ONS_ALPHA label from our documentation.
